# SourceTree error when switching branch back to master

Tags: git, git-branch, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a git repository I'm working with through SourceTree, and in the pursuit of a different error I switched from my master (I think) to branch "A" that I hadn't yet merged with the master.  When I tried to switch back to the master branch from branch "A", I get the following error:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false -c 
credential.helper=manager-st checkout master
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by 
checkout:
    GenReport.m
    GetTideCons.m
    OvernightQCReportTemplate.xlsx
    VarLowPassChebIIfilt.m
    enableDisableAll.m
    nonmatfiles/MgL_logo.png
    selectiveEnable.m
Please move or remove them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

"File Status" shows what looks like is all the files created since the one commit I made on branch A as untracked files.

How do I switch back to the latest commit on my master branch?  I'm really new to git/SourceTree and I don't know what would happen to my files if I remove these unstaged files.  I was pretty much down with this software before I tried switching branches, so if I lose things permanently getting them back will take time I really don't have right now.

Thank you in advance for any help you can give me!

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is stash your current changes. You can do the following from the Repository option.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about what's in those files and you would like to take a closer look later on to what's going on, then just stash whatever you have laying arounf your working tree (you can check it later on):

`git add .; git stash save "Will see what's going on later on"`

Later on, you will be able to see what's going on when you have some time.